# AlphaAnimation - Initial state set in XML

Tags: android, animation, alpha

I know there are lots of questions out there on this topic but no answer covers what I want to do.

Alpha state should start as 0.2 - then upon completion of an action it animates to 1.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="0.8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        **android:alpha="0.2"**
        android:id="@+id/stage_one">
...
</LinearLayout>



AlphaAnimation alphaAnim = new AlphaAnimation((float) 0.2, (float) 1);
            alphaAnim.setDuration(1000);
            alphaAnim.setFillAfter(true);
            alphaAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
            stage1.startAnimation(alphaAnim);
```

However this fades between 0.2/0.2 and 1/0.2 (it fades from 0.04 - 0.2)- the fade is shown as a percentage of the alpha value set in XML.

Yes if i remove the xml value then the animation works from 0.2 - 1, however i need this view to be initialised at 0.2 then  fade up to 1 when a button is pressed at some point in the future. - Yes the same issue occurs if I initialise the alpha value of the view in the onCreate method.

Thanks in advance.

A

Answer (score 0):

Stupidly got to set the alpha to one then perform the animation.

```
stage1.setAlpha(1.0F);
AlphaAnimation alphaAnim = new AlphaAnimation((float) 0.2, (float) 1);
            alphaAnim.setDuration(1000);
            alphaAnim.setFillAfter(true);
            alphaAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
            stage1.startAnimation(alphaAnim);
```